# Nginx rewrite problem

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, nginx

Every single page requested is passed to "check.php":

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://localhost/check.php?page=$1
```

"check.php" verify several security things then require the requested page:

```
<?php
    // ... security stuff

    require_once ($myRequestedPage);
?>
```

The problem is, in an HTML file, any external style isn't loaded, just scripts:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <!-- Do not load -->

        <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Do not load -->

        <script src="js.js"></script> <!-- Load -->

        <style>
            @import url("css.css"); <!-- Do not load -->
        </style>

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

Any clues ? Thanks.

Comment: Are the stylesheets in the same folder and at the same level as the requested page? Also on an unrelated note, since you are using HTML5 standards you don't need to close the self closing tags like meta, link, br, etc.

Comment: This question have nothing to do with javascript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you currently care about manually setting the specific mime-type for every rewritten file via the PHP `header` command? The mime types differ for javascript, css and HTML files. This alone can lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you ONLY route requests for files that don't exist to check.php. This prevents requests for "style.css" from being rewritten to check.php which is currently what is happening. EVERYTHING is being sent to check.php (even your stylesheets).

```
# Route all requests for non-existent files to index.php
if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /check.php/$1 last;
}

# Pass PHP scripts to php-fastcgi listening on port 9000
location ~ \.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: That might bypass existing PHP files as well (which might not be desired). Just exluding some file extensions (css, js, jpg, png, ...) from rewriting is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Firebug:

http://getfirebug.com/

That way, you can inspect what the browser is seeing and attempt to find what the problem is, which could be relating to paths (as Kyle mentions), or headers (are non text/css headers being sent due to the rewrite), or some other issue.

Checking what was downloaded, you can use the CSS tab and then look at each one of the files you were expecting to download. If your browser could not get the file, you will see an error. See the *all.css* portion of this screenshot:

[image: Firebug CSS tab]

Then, you could inspect the Net tab and look at the headers/response for the css files, to see what was returned, as illustrated in the below screenshot (try headers to see if the Content-Type text/css is correct:

[image: Firebug Net CSS Response tab]

Here is the header content-type highlighted:

[image: Content-type text/css]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a / before the CSS link:

```
<link href="/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
<link href="../css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Seems kind of trivial, but these things have given me similar problems before :)